# Select TOP 2 with DISTINCT name SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, distinct, distinct-values

I need to get the top 2 clients that spend more money but without repeating.

I have this code:

```
Select DISTINCT Top 2 Clientes.Nome, Clientes.NCartao, Vendas.ValorCIva 
from Clientes AS Cli, Vendas
INNER JOIN Clientes ON Clientes.IdCliente = Vendas.IdCliente
order by Vendas.ValorCIva DESC
```

and I have this result:

```
Client          Number  Total
José Pinto      123456  8,48
José Pinto      123456  6,52
Joao Ferreira   564789  5,75
```

but i want this:

```
Client          Number  Total
José Pinto      123456   15
Joao Ferreira   564789  5,75
```

Comment: This doesn't exactly relate to your question but it looks like you have an unnecessary / unreferenced cross-joined table in your original query: `Clientes AS Cli,`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way of doing it:

```
select Top 2 Clientes.Nome, Clientes.NCartao, sum(Vendas.ValorCIva) ValorCIva 
from Clientes AS Cli, Vendas INNER JOIN Clientes ON Clientes.IdCliente = Vendas.IdCliente 
group by Clientes.Nome, Clientes.NCartao
order by sum(Vendas.ValorCIva) DESC
```

Comment: I think if you look closely, you'll see that OP is `SUM`ing the total.

Comment: Thks a lot, you help me much in my problem

Answer (score 0):

if you dont want to repeat that client put a GROUP BY so  it will automatically display each client and dont repeat itself, something like this..

```
Select Top 2 Clientes.Nome, Clientes.NCartao, Vendas.ValorCIva 
FROM Clientes AS Cli, Vendas
INNER JOIN Clientes ON Clientes.IdCliente = Vendas.IdCliente
GROUP BY Clientes.Nome
ORDER BY Clientes.Nome
```

Comment: This will fail because `Clientes.NCartao` and `Vendas.ValorCIva` are not in the group by, it also doesnt address the addition that OP is talking about. Magandang umaga. :)

Comment: ohh i see i just copy your query then put some group by :) hahaha sorry